# PowerShell - why doesn't 'contains' work on a string pulled from an array?

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, contains

trying to work this one out and not having much luck really. The if statement from the following block of code is never true, which I don't understand:

```
$array1 = "red", "blue", "green", "yellow"
$array2 = "rose", "sky", "grass", "sand"
$both_arrays = $array1, $array2

for ($c=0; $c -lt 4; $c++) {

$object = $both_arrays[0][$c]
$colour = $both_arrays[1][$c]

Write-Host $c "-" $object
Write-Host $c "-" $colour

if ( ($colour.contains("green") ) ) { Write-Host "HELL YEAH! Green is my favourite colour!" }

}
```

Output as follows:

```
0 - red
0 - rose
1 - blue
1 - sky
2 - green
2 - grass
3 - yellow
3 - sand
```

It works fine if we're just dealing with one array though:

```
$array1 = "red", "blue", "green", "yellow"

for ($c=0; $c -lt 4; $c++) {

$colour = $array1[$c]

Write-Host $c "-" $colour

if ( ($colour.contains("green") ) ) { Write-Host "HELL YEAH! Green is my favourite colour!" }

}
```

Output comes out as expected:

```
0 - red
1 - blue
2 - green
HELL YEAH! Green is my favourite colour!
3 - yellow
```

What the smeg is going on? Help appreciated!

Still getting an error with an example of the above code when I attempt to apply the concept to another script I'm writing:

```
for ($c=0; $c -lt 3; $c++) { #$arrCheckpoint, 

$ckname = $arrCheckpointNameAndStatus[0][$c]
$ckstatus = $arrCheckpointNameAndStatus[1][$c]

Write-Host $ckname

if ( ($ckname.contains("Standard Checkpoint") ) ) { Write-Host "Hit." }

}

Write-Host "End of Script"
```

It throws the following error:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'contains'.
At C:\script.ps1:225 char:27
+     if ( ($ckname.contains <<<< ("Standard Checkpoint") ) ) { Write-Host "Hit." }
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (contains:String) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Really starting to bug me now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have the array indexing of your object and color arrays reversed.

Comment: Oh... * embarrassed* Should be 1,0, not 0,1... Do I feel dumb :D